# Is there a way to list all the cached scripts in redis?

Tags: scripting, redis

```
SCRIPT EXISTS sha1
```

The above will tell you if a script exists but is there a way to list all the cached scripts in redis?

thanks!

Comment: No there isn't - why do you need that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this, but what's the purpose of listing loaded scripts **if the scripts need to be loaded from the application layer**. That is, *what scripts are loaded* is a known information by your code.

I don't know what programming language or framework you're currently using in your solution, but whatever platform you're using, you just need to put some code to intercept the moment where you load a script to Redis and fire an event to be handled somewhere.

Comment: We're using twemproxy so we can't use SCRIPT LOAD. This was more for debugging purposes to see if scripts were been cached under a different sha than expected.

Comment: Checking scripts make sense when server was hacked.